# make it impossible to download the audio files

Tags: amazon-s3, mp3, audio-streaming, audio-player, amazon-elastic-transcoder

So guys, how do I prevent users from downloading audio files on my web app (running springboot in backend) by accessing the s3 url !
I want to make it impossible to download the audio files in my website ! Any suggestions pls ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean that you want to make it impossible to download the audio files, but still allow streaming them for playback.

You can't.

If it can be played, it can be downloaded.  Simple as that.

At best, you can [sign your S3 URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) so that they expire after a short period of time.  This gives you control over who accesses your audio files, and prevents them from showing up in searches, or linked to from other sites.  You can also look into Encrypted Media Extensions, but it's not all that useful for audio since audio is trivially digitally captured on the output.